# Do these implications hold in general?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let  $a,b,x \in \mathbb{R}$

(a) $ab>1 $ ,$a<1$ $\Rightarrow$ $b>1$

(b)$x(x-2a^2)>0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $|x-a^2|>a^2$

My problem is  I cannot give a counterexample for (a) and (b) .

For (a) I  simply have $$1<ab<b $$

and for (b) $$|x-a^2|>a^2 \Leftrightarrow (x-a^2)^2>a^4 \Leftrightarrow x(x-2a^2)>0 $$

Comment: Re (a): Think of *negative* numbers.

Comment: I have for example  a=-2 , b=-3

Comment: Yes, that is a counterexample.

Comment: Your proof for (b) is correct. It holds for any real $a,x$.

Answer (score 2):

For b) note that $x(x-2a^{2}) >0$ iff ($x>0$ and $x >2a^{2}$) or ($x <0$ and $x <2a^{2}$) iff $x>2a^{2}$ or $x <0$. But this is true iff $x$ does not lie in $[0,2a^{2}]$ which is true iff $x-a^{2}$ does not lie in $[-a^{2},a^{2}]$ iff $|x-a^{2}| >a^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For (b) there is no conterexample, since

$$(x-a^2)^2>a^4 \iff x^2-2xa^2+a^4> a^4 \iff x^2-2xa^2 >0 \iff x(x-2a^2) >0.$$